# H3 DGGS : General questions

Tags: uber-api, h3

Good afternoon,

I'm a newbie to H3. Before reading deeply the documentation and go further on tests with H3, I'm taking the liberty to ask you general questions regarding H3.In advance sorry if my questions seem naive or clumsy.

1. Which bindings are recommended for using H3? Is there one more suitable one for each fonctionality ? data integration ? display? Raster supported ? Sampling/quantification?  : python? geopandas with jupyter notebook? postgis? R ? Bigquery ? js,etc.?
2. We wonder about the possibility with H3 to consider DGGS maritime trafficability shorter path analysis with some constraints. I past below a screen shot.

[image: Maritime DGGS]

3. Does H3 allows the integration/fusion/combine of data? We would like do some test with multi-source/multi-date data fusion combination for the creation of a DTM (topographic or bathymetric)?
4. Is it possible to assign a weight to the THR data (importance flag in order to not decimate the Very Hihgt Resolution). So, Is it possible to manage and define metadata ?
5. Which type of data the tool is able to integrate ? (raster ? polygon? line? point ? point cloud?).
6. Does the tool offer different methods in terms of sampling and quantification? Is it possible for the user to decide at what level in the hierarchy of cells it is possible to assign the data?
7. Finally does H3 is compliant with OGC DGGS abstract standard. If no, do you know the existing gap ?

In advance, thank you very much for your useful replies.

Kind regards.

Comment: For future questions, StackOverflow works best when you ask one question at a time. Good questions are specific and clear, and usually have a factual (rather than subjective) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Best-effort answers to your questions:

A. **Bindings**: The bindings we're aware of are [listed here](https://h3geo.org/#/documentation/community/bindings). The bindings for Java, JavaScript, and Python are probably the best-maintained (though Python has been undergoing a major refactor and might be best used when this is finished).

B. **Path Analysis**: I haven't worked with this, but [this tutorial](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#pathfinding) suggests that all you need to implement this in a hex grid are neighbors and a distance function. Neighbors in H3 are available via `kRing(origin, 1)` and distance can be calculated via `h3Distance(origin, target)` (with some limitations at present - the two cells cannot be too far apart and the path cannot cross a pentagon).

C. **Merging Data Sources**: H3 is an excellent choice as a *common unit* for analysis that merges multiple data sources - you can convert multiple sources into H3 and then e.g. perform cell-based raster arithmetic to get a value for each hexagon. The H3 library itself only offers conversion functions, not data merging functions.

D. I don't fully understand this question, but it would be outside the purview of the H3 library.

E. **Data Type Conversion**: The library provides strong support for converting polygon data (via `polyfill`) and point data (via `h3ToGeo`). Raster data would probably need to be converted into a grid of points for conversion to cells. H3 uses a spherical plane that doesn't consider altitude, so it can't be used to convert a 3d point cloud without external logic about how to project the points onto the surface. Note that the H3 library itself has no logic to deal with file formats, etc.

F. **Sampling/Quantification**: The choice of resolution is user-specified, but otherwise the H3 library does not explicitly deal with sampling or quantification. Points are assigned to the cells in which they are found; when using `polyfill`, cells are assigned to polygons in which their centers are found. Further sampling choices are left to the user.

G. **Adherence to DGGS Standard**: See [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/01b6/ae26c8f5456a4f7c3c23ec96d0aa76809a18.pdf) for an assessment of H3 and an alternative DGGS in relation to the standard.